# Вставка EditText в шапку макета Scrolling Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

В Android Studio есть стандартный макет Scrolling Activity. По умолчанию в верхней части размещается **название макета**, которое при прокрутке уменьшается и уходит вверх.

Как разместить в шапке элемент **EditText** вместо **названия макета**? Хочу вводить название группы на этом месте.

С размещением **EditText** вроде нет проблем, просто вставляю внутри **CollapsingToolbarLayout**. А вот с названием макета у меня возникают сложности - при попытках удалить его, приложение становится нерабочим. Помогите разобраться, самому не хватает опыта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай, вот код макета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.kulikovman.todolist.GroupActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_group" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/addTaskButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по разному. Например сделать заголовок `CollapsingToolbarLayout` прозрачным так:

```
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
```

Или вовсе его отменить так:

```
app:titleEnabled="false"
```

Comment: Может неправильно делаю. Вставил указанную строку в **CollapsingToolbarLayout** - на макете заголовок стал прозрачным, но при запуске на устройстве все равно остается белым.

Comment: Попробуйте ещё что-то типа `app:titleEnabled="false"`

Comment: Спасибо. Второй вариант помог, получилось даже лучше, чем я ожидал.